# SeekableByteChannel russian chars

Tags: java, encoding, java-7, nio, cyrillic

Recently I've started learning about ***java.nio***. And I have an example in my textbook how to read text file with ***SeekableByteChannel***:

```
int count;
Path path;

try {
    path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/desktop/text.txt");
} catch (InvalidPathException e) {
    out.println(e.getMessage());
    return;
}

try (SeekableByteChannel channel = Files.newByteChannel(path)) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(128);

    do {
        count = channel.read(buffer);

        if (count != -1) {
            buffer.rewind();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                out.print((char) buffer.get());
        }
    } while (count != -1);

} catch (IOException e) {
    out.println("File not found!!!");
}

out.flush();
```

So I've made a text file with english and russian words in it using an **ANSI** encoding. And this is what I get:

[image: output result]

Method *buffer.get()* returns *byte* value and russian characters start from somewhere 1000. So I've changed encoding to **UTF-8** and used another method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i += 2)
    out.print(buffer.getChar()); //reads 2 bytes and converts them to char
```

But this gives me a line of question marks.

So does anyone know how to properly read russian text using ***SeekableByteChannel***?

Comment: text.txt could be nailed better for the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getChar()` of `ByteBuffer` reads two bytes and interprets them as high byte and low byte of a `char`, in other words, invariably uses the `UTF-16` encoding. Generally, you shouldn’t try to puzzle bytes to `String`s manually, not with the old I/O API and not with NIO. Just to mention one thing you would have to deal with when trying to decode bytes from a buffer manually, is that the bytes in your buffer may not end at a character boundary for multi-byte encodings.

If you want to read text from a `SeekableByteChannel`, you may use [`Channels.newReader(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newReader(java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20java.lang.String)) to construct a `Reader` using the specified charset to decode the bytes.

But of course, you can skip the `Channel` stuff entirely and use [`Files.newBufferedReader(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) to create a `Reader` right from the `Path`.

By the way, the example code is questionable, even for reading a sequence of bytes. Here is a simplified example:

```
Path path=Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home")).resolve("desktop/text.txt");
try(FileChannel channel=FileChannel.open(path)) {
  ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(128);
  while(channel.read(buffer)!=-1) {
    buffer.flip();
    while(buffer.hasRemaining())
        System.out.printf("%02x ", buffer.get());
    buffer.clear();
    System.out.println();
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

A `ByteBuffer` knows how many bytes it contains (i.e. have been put into it by the read operation). With `flip` you prepare the buffer for reading them out, e.g. with a loop like in the example or by writing into another channel. When you know that you have processed the entire contents, you can use `clear` to set the buffer in the initial state where it can be filled from beginning up to the end.

Otherwise, if it may contain unprocessed data, use `compact` instead, this will move the unprocessed data to the beginning of the buffer and prepare it for receiving more data *after* them, so after a subsequent `read` and `flip` you have the pending data of the previous iteration followed by the data of the most recent read operation ready for being processed as a single sequence. (This is how the `Reader` will deal with incomplete character sequences internally while decoding)